# Does there is a Angular8 testing method to find nested component instances?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-test

I have an angular 8 application. I am testing `MyCustomComponent` with the current template :

```
<mat-card>
    <table>
       <another-custom-component></another-custom-component>
    </table>
</mat-card>
```

To get a child component of my current tested component I use :

```
fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(AnotherCustomComponent))
```

But in this example in my `fixture.debugElement.childNodes` I would find only one node, the MatCard.

How to get nested childs ? 
I guess I could try to find the wanted child with recursive function, but does there is any built-in method for that ?

Answer (score 0):

For every directive you should have separate describe and for every describe you can have different beforeEach. You should test one child at a time within it's parent, so it is kind of anti-pattern to test all your child-tree at once.

Comment: Yes I agree but it's to ensure the nexted child get the right parameter from the grand X parent

Comment: You can get them from  getElement().componentInstance and test for value and other properties